# Issues in routing to another component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have components called `demo` and `home`.I have placed `demo` component in `app.component.html` file. The `demo` component looks like this:

[image]

As shown in the image, The `demo` component is having `button (HOME)`. For this button i have given an router link to navigate to `home`component. Now it is navigating to home `component` fine but both `demo` and `home` are displaying on the same page. I want to route it in seperate page.

Stackblitz [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-koqctg?file=app/demo/demo.component.html)

Comment: That StackBlitz is not running the app for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show `Demo` component by default but remove it when route changes then update your route config like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DemoComponent },   // this will route to demo component by default;
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
];
```

And just have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your `app.component.html`.

In your example you have `demo component` added statically to the `app component` so this will mean it will always be there(unless you add some if conditions)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-fkwdrm?file=app%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

app.component.html (remove demo component)

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

update your router to add the demo path:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'; 
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DemoComponent } from './demo/demo.component';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'demo', component: DemoComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Issue is you are rendering your demo component outside of the router outlet.

Comment: If i remove `app-demo` in `app.component.html`. I can't show the `demo` page.According to my requirement i should display the `demo`page as landing page.

Comment: Each object within routes defines a path and a component to use.  You can update the path to be whatever landing page you want.

Comment: Shouldn't he edit the `app.component.html` too?

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto...editing app.component.html is the first line in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the app.component.html file from your StackBlitz:

```
<app-demo></app-demo>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This tells the Angular router to display the app-demo component and whatever component the router is supposed to display.  Just remove the app-demo from the main app component and you should be good to go.